# Need to implode a slice of a JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, range, slice

I have this JSON object containing timestamps and words and other elements of a transcription made with Amazon Transcribe:

```
[  
    {  
        "start_time":"29.420",
        "end_time":"40.500",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.4332",
                "content":"Foo"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"156.087",
        "end_time":"156.567",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.8786",
                "content":"Hello"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"156.597",
        "end_time":"157.737",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.9439",
                "content":"how"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"157.737",
        "end_time":"157.917",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.9916",
                "content":"are"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"157.917",
        "end_time":"158.287",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.6898",
                "content":"you"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"158.717",
        "end_time":"160.637",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.6357",
                "content":"Bar"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    }
]
```

I need to return the content between `start_time` = 100 and `end_time` = 160:

> Hello how are you

I tried converting it to an array using `json_decode` and then manipulated with `ksort`, `implode`, `slice`, *etc.* without success.

Comment: show your code so we can take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the JSON to get an array, then loop through the records and only concatenate (or store or whatever you need) those with `$start_date > 100 && $end_time < 160`.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$endResult = "";
foreach ($data as $res) {
    if ($res["start_time"] > 100 && $res["end_time"] < 160) {
        $endResult .= $res["alternatives"][0]["content"]." ";
    }
}
var_dump($endResult); // Hello how are you
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/I42sI)

Or you can [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the array with the same condition and get an array with only the elements you need, to further process later as you need:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$endResult = array_filter($data, function ($el) {
    return $el["start_time"] > 100 && $el["end_time"] < 160;
});
var_dump($endResult); // only elements within that time
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6gjcW)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this ? instead of going in foreach loop the second time, you can resort the array to fit your needs.

```
$array = json_decode($json);

$data = [];

foreach($array as $el) {
    $object = (object) $el;
    $start = $object->start_time;
    $stop  = $object->end_time;
    $content = $object->alternatives[0]->content;
    $data[] =  (array) [
        'start' => (float) $start,
        'stop'  => (float) $stop,
        'content' => (string) $content,
    ];
}

$between = [100,160];

foreach($data as $el) {

 if($el['start'] >= $between[0] && $el['stop'] <= $between[1]) {
     echo $el['content'] . ' ';
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could converts your JSON-encoded string `$json` into a PHP variable by using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-decode.php) function. Then you will be able to iterate it and apply the conditions to build your content:

```
<?php
$json = '[  
    {  
        "start_time":"29.420",
        "end_time":"40.500",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.4332",
                "content":"Foo"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"156.087",
        "end_time":"156.567",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.8786",
                "content":"Hello"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"156.597",
        "end_time":"157.737",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.9439",
                "content":"how"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"157.737",
        "end_time":"157.917",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.9916",
                "content":"are"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"157.917",
        "end_time":"158.287",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.6898",
                "content":"you"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    },
    {  
        "start_time":"158.717",
        "end_time":"160.637",
        "alternatives":[  
            {  
                "confidence":"0.6357",
                "content":"Bar"
            }
        ],
        "type":"pronunciation"
    }
]';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$content = "";
foreach ($json as $item) {
    if ($item["start_time"] >= 100 && $item["end_time"] <= 160) {
        $content .= $item["alternatives"][0]["content"] . " ";
    }
}
echo trim($content);
```